# CSS Transitions in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have an HTML table with collapsible/expandable sections. The CSS transition animates smoothly in every single browser ***except*** Safari. The collapse animation is super jerky on Safari, but the expand animation is okay. I'm running the latest: Safari 16.2 on macOS 13.1.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be fantastic. Thanks.

```js
function toggleSpecCat(el, cls) {
   el.closest('tr').classList.toggle('Closed');
   document.querySelector(`.${cls}`).classList.toggle('Closed');
}
```

```css
* {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
#Products {
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
#Products th,
#Products td {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   background-color: white;
   width: calc((100% - 180px) / 3);
   min-width: 200px;
   padding: 9px;
}
#Products th:first-child,
#Products td:first-child {
   width: 180px;
}
#Products th {
   background-color: #555;
   color: white;
}
#Products th:first-child {
   text-align: left;
}
#Products th:last-child,
#Products td:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}
#Products .SpecCatHeader * {
   background-color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
#Products .SpecCat th,
#Products .SpecCat td {
   transition: line-height 0.3s,
      padding-top 0.3s,
      padding-bottom 0.3s;
}
#Products .SpecCat.Closed th,
#Products .SpecCat.Closed td {
   opacity: 0;
   line-height: 0;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="Products">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>PRODUCTS</th>
         <th>Product 1</th>
         <th>Product 2</th>
         <th>Product 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
      <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatBattery')">
         <span>Battery</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatBattery">
      <tr>
         <th>Charging Cable Length</th>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Charging Port</th>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>DC Input Power</th>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Quick Charging Times</th>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Recharge Time</th>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Runtime</th>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Wireless Charging</th>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
      <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatHeadphone')">
         <span>Headphone</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatHeadphone">
      <tr>
         <th>Active Noise Cancellation</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Controls/Microphone Location</th>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Diaphragm</th>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Driver Size</th>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Driver Type</th>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Connection / Wearing Style</th>
         <td>Headband</td>
         <td>Headband</td>
         <td>Headband</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Design</th>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Swivel</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Foldable</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Full Remote OS Support</th>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Magnet Type</th>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Number of Drivers</th>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Sensors</th>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Voice Coil</th>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
      <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatMicrophone')">
         <span>Microphone</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatMicrophone">
      <tr>
         <th>Beamforming Support</th>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>No</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Noise Canceling</th>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Number of Mics</th>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <td>MEMS</td>
         <td>MEMS</td>
         <td>MEMS</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
      <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatPerformance')">
         <span>Performance</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatPerformance">
      <tr>
         <th>Frequency Response</th>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Sensitivity</th>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Storage Capacity</th>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I confirm what you’re seeing, and my answer is that this is Apple’s bug to resolve. [Report it](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: I suppose I could just use `display: none` for Safari and ditch the animation for that browser. Ugh.

Comment: No, don't mess up your application like that. The result isn't perfect but it works well enough. But I do encourage you to report the bug, it's little things like this which Apple may not come across otherwise, and reporting keeps the pressure on them to produce a quality product.

Comment: That is indeed a WebKit bug, you can track its resolution at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251911.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing `line-height` from my transition.

```js
function toggleSpecCat(el, cls) {
   el.closest('tr').classList.toggle('Closed');
   document.querySelector(`.${cls}`).classList.toggle('Closed');
}
```

```css
* {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
main {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
}
#Products {
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
#Products th,
#Products td {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   background-color: white;
   width: calc((100% - 180px) / 3);
   min-width: 200px;
   padding: 9px;
}
#Products th:first-child {
   width: 180px;
}
#Products th {
   background-color: #555;
   color: white;
}
#Products th:first-child {
   text-align: left;
}
#Products th:last-child,
#Products td:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}
#Products .SpecCatHeader * {
   background-color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
#Products .SpecCat th,
#Products .SpecCat td {
   transition: padding-top 0.3s, padding-bottom 0.3s;
}
#Products .SpecCat.Closed th,
#Products .SpecCat.Closed td {
   opacity: 0;
   line-height: 0;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="Products">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>PRODUCTS</th>
         <th>Product 1</th>
         <th>Product 2</th>
         <th>Product 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
         <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatBattery')">
            <span>Battery</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatBattery">
      <tr>
         <th>Charging Cable Length</th>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
         <td>7.87&quot; / 19.99 cm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Charging Port</th>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
         <td>USB Type-C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>DC Input Power</th>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
         <td>5 VDC</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Quick Charging Times</th>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
         <td>10 Minutes for 5 Hours</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Recharge Time</th>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
         <td>3 Hours</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Runtime</th>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
         <td>30 Hours (BT+ANC) 38 Hours (BT) 200 Hours (Standby)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Wireless Charging</th>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
         <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatHeadphone')">
            <span>Headphone</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatHeadphone">
      <tr>
         <th>Active Noise Cancellation</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Controls/Microphone Location</th>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
         <td>Controls: Earpiece (Side Unspecified) Microphone: Earpiece (Side Unspecified)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Diaphragm</th>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
         <td>Aluminum-Coated</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Driver Size</th>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
         <td>1.57&quot; / 40 mm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Driver Type</th>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
         <td>Dynamic</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Connection / Wearing Style</th>
         <td>Headband</td>
         <td>Headband</td>
         <td>Headband</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Design</th>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
         <td>Over-Ear (Circumaural), Closed-Back</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Earpiece Swivel</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Foldable</th>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
         <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Full Remote OS Support</th>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
         <td>Android, iOS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Magnet Type</th>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
         <td>Neodymium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Number of Drivers</th>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
         <td>1, per Earpiece</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Sensors</th>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
         <td>Proximity, Touch</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Voice Coil</th>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
         <td>Copper-Clad Aluminum Wire</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
         <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatMicrophone')">
            <span>Microphone</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatMicrophone">
      <tr>
         <th>Beamforming Support</th>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>No</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Noise Canceling</th>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
         <td>Not Specified by Manufacturer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Number of Mics</th>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <td>MEMS</td>
         <td>MEMS</td>
         <td>MEMS</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="SpecCatHeader">
         <td colspan="4" onclick="toggleSpecCat(this, 'CatPerformance')">
            <span>Performance</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="SpecCat CatPerformance">
      <tr>
         <th>Frequency Response</th>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
         <td>4 Hz to 40 kHz (Wired)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Sensitivity</th>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
         <td>101 dB at 1 kHz (Passive) 105 dB at 1 kHz (Active)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Storage Capacity</th>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>None</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```